# Viewpager pauses/stuck

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I have viewpager with tabs below my appbar layout.
My toolbar has flags scroll|enterAlways.

The view pager tabs have recyclerviews.

When I scroll the recyclerview, and then if I try to switch between tabs by swiping, the viewpager swipe gets stuck/freezes for a while. I have to repeatedly try to swipe between tabs to make it work.

The issue happens when the toolbar scrolls with the recyclerview.

The issue gets resolved by removing the scroll flags of the toolbar i.e. when it no longer scrolls with the recyclerview inside viewpager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.micronic.myspecs.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/myAdView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.micronic.myspecs.FontAwareTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                fontPath="mnt.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My Specs" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="News" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phones" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reviews" />

            </com.micronic.myspecs.FontAwareTabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.micronic.myspecs.views.MyAdView
        android:id="@+id/myAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please somebody help me solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the relevant code so that we can best help you.

Comment: Anybody there to help?